# AWS Lambda request with Amazon Gateway Proxy Integration, queryStringParameter pass through issues

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, axios, proxy, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to use AWS gateway as a means to call a third party API and control use.  As of now I have a lambda function that can accept an event JSON and get tide data from the external API.

**Lambda function axios module loaded via zip.**

```
const axios = require('axios');

 
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    
    const url = 'https://api.marea.ooo/v2/tides';
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        params: { 
            latitude: event.latitude,
            longitude: event.longitude  
        },
        headers: {
            'x-marea-api-token': API_KEY
        },
    };
     
     const response = await axios.get(url, options)
      return {
             "statusCode": 200,
             "headers": {
                 "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                 "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*"
             }, 
             "body": JSON.stringify(response.data),
         };
     
 }
```

**Event JSON:** *Used for test in Lambda Console*

```
{
  "latitude": 53,
  "longitude": 78
}
```

This will respond with success in Lambda test.  Event parameters are passed through appropriately and in the above example I am able to get the values in the event JSON to be used as the query strings for the API call.

I have this hooked up to an AWS Gateway API with proxy integration.  When I run a GET test in AWS Gateway using the Query Strings input field, "latitude=53&longitude=78" I get an Axios error. I have URL Query String parameters for both latitude and longitude set in the method request.

The only way to get the test in AWS Gateway to result is to hardcode a set of longitude and latitude params in the lambda function...

```
params: {
            latitude: 36,
            longitude: 78
        }
```

If I do this and run the test I get an API response passed back through from the 3rd party.

**QUESTION** Why is my parameter pass through failing even in AWS Gateway test?

I have tried other iterations of event.queryStringParameters.latitude, etc.  It is my understanding that with proxy integration I should be able to call event.latitude.  Neither work as anticipated.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: In case of API Gateway proxy through the event structure is different. Output the event and you will know the difference. Also for lambda test event create a API Gateway event instead of Hello World event.

Comment: If the API gateway is in Lambda proxy integration, the event object in your case is going to be `queryStringParameters: { latitude: '53', longitude: '78' }`. So you should be able to access the value with `event.queryStringParameters.latitude`. If you have already tried it and you are not able to access the params. Then most probably lambda proxy configuration is not correctly configured. Under `Integration Request` ensure that the `Use Lambda Proxy integration` is checked.